# Обводка круга на canvas(рулетка)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Помогите пожалуйста сделать 2 обводки, с канвасом никогда не работал(
Как на рисунке, только на 360 градусов

1. обводка нужна на границах рулетки(360 градусов)
2. И вторая обводка c точками этого же круга[image: введите сюда описание изображения].
   Или как 2 вариант.
   Как наложить круг, чтобы не закрывала эту.
   Сенк заранее

   ```js
   var colors = ["#0169D3"];
   var quienes = ["ничего", "скидка на все 300руб.", "скидка на все 10%", "увы, в другой раз", "скидка на все 5%",
     "секретная акция", "подарок сюрприз", "скидка на все 1000 руб.", "увы, в другой раз", "бесплатная", "доставка"
   ];

   var startAngle = 0;
   var arc = Math.PI / 5;
   var spinTimeout = null;
   var spinArcStart = 10;
   var spinTime = 10;
   var spinTimeTotal = 10;
   var ctx;

   function drawRouletteWheel() {
     let canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");
     if (canvas.getContext) {
       let outsideRadius = 190;
       let textRadius = 110;
       let insideRadius = 30;
       ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
       ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
       ctx.strokeStyle = "black"; // Цвет границ
       ctx.font = 'bold 14px sans-serif';

       for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         let angle = startAngle + i * arc;
         ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
         ctx.beginPath(); //контур
         ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false); //дуга
         ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true); //дуга
         ctx.stroke(); //фигура
         ctx.fill();
         ctx.save();
         ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
         ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
         ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
         ctx.shadowColor = "black";
         ctx.fillStyle = "white";
         ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
         ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 3 + Math.PI / 150); //Поворачиваем текст
         let text = quienes[i];
         ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0); //fillText - текст с заливкой. 
         ctx.restore(); //Возвращает ранее сохраненное состояние и атрибуты
       }

       //Arrow
       ctx.strokeStyle = 'navy'; // Set line colour.
       ctx.fillStyle = 'aqua'; // Set fill colour.
       ctx.lineWidth = 2;
       ctx.beginPath(); // Begin path.
       ctx.moveTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
       ctx.lineTo(250 + 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
       ctx.lineTo(250 + 6, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
       ctx.lineTo(250 + 15, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
       ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 33));
       ctx.lineTo(250 - 15, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
       ctx.lineTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
       ctx.lineTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
       ctx.stroke();
       ctx.fill();
     }
   }

   function rotateWheel() {
     clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
     spinTime = spinTime + 10; //делай оборот больше 360 градусов
     if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
       return;
     }
     let spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal); //метод easeout - анимация в обратном порядке
     startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
     drawRouletteWheel();
     spinTimeout = setInterval('rotateWheel()'); // вызываем круг один раз, через определенный интервал времени
   }
   // При остановке прокрутки, будет показывать число по середине круга.

   /*function stopRotateWheel() {
     let degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
     let arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
     let index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
     ctx.save();
     ctx.font = 'bold 32px sans-serif';
     ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
     ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
     ctx.shadowBlur    = 2;
     ctx.shadowColor   = "black";
     let text = quienes[index]
     ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
     ctx.restore();
     alert(text);
     
   }*/

   function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
     let ts = (t /= d) * t;
     let tc = ts * t;
     return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
   }

   function spin() {
     spinAngleStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 16); //random - Возвращает случайное число между 0 и 1 * 100
     spinTime = 0;
     spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1500;
     rotateWheel();
   }
   drawRouletteWheel();
   ```

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <canvas id="wheelcanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
     <sumbit><a class="spin__button" type="button" onclick="spin();" id="btn_rodar" href="#">Крути</a></submit>

   </body>

   </html>
   ```

Comment: Прикольная штука, только зачем каждый раз перерисовывать рулетку. Надо единожды нарисовать на неотображаемом холсте, потом добавлять на этот холст с одновременным вращением осей координат. А кружочек по периметру то нарисовать какая проблема? Можно даже указать толщину линии, и просто интструментом `stroke` нарисовать, ничего перекрываться не будет. Можно за счет `globalCompositionOperation` отрисовать и `fill`-круги как бы в обратном порядке. Но вы же можете и вначале их нарисовать, зачем под рулетку подсовывать. Одним словом, что здесь может вызывать проблему НЕ ЯСНО!

Comment: Проблема в том, что в программировании совсем недавно и с канвас не работал(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ревизию кода делать не буду. Самое простое - добавить ободок с помощью метода `stroke()`, предварительно задав толщину линии `lineWidth`. Чтобы настройки не мешали дальнейшему рисованию, "оборачиваю" этот кусок кода в `ctx.save()` ___ `ctx.restore()`:

```
ctx.save();
        
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.strokeStyle = colors[0];

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius + 12, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.restore();
```

```js
var colors = ["#0169D3"];
var quienes = ["ничего", "скидка на все 300руб.", "скидка на все 10%", "увы, в другой раз", "скидка на все 5%",
"секретная акция", "подарок сюрприз", "скидка на все 1000 руб.", "увы, в другой раз", "бесплатная", "доставка"
];

var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / 5;
var spinTimeout = null;
var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 10;
var spinTimeTotal = 10;
var ctx;

function drawRouletteWheel() {
let canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");
if (canvas.getContext) {
    let outsideRadius = 190;
    let textRadius = 110;
    let insideRadius = 30;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    
    ctx.save();
    
    ctx.lineWidth = 15;
    ctx.strokeStyle = colors[0];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius + 12, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.restore();
    
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black"; // Цвет границ
    ctx.font = 'bold 14px sans-serif';

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let angle = startAngle + i * arc;
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
    ctx.beginPath(); //контур
    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false); //дуга
    ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true); //дуга
    ctx.stroke(); //фигура
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
    ctx.shadowColor = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
    ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 3 + Math.PI / 150); //Поворачиваем текст
    let text = quienes[i];
    ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0); //fillText - текст с заливкой. 
    ctx.restore(); //Возвращает ранее сохраненное состояние и атрибуты
    }

    //Arrow
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'navy'; // Set line colour.
    ctx.fillStyle = 'aqua'; // Set fill colour.
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath(); // Begin path.
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 6, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 15, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 33));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 15, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}
}

function rotateWheel() {
clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
spinTime = spinTime + 10; //делай оборот больше 360 градусов
if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    return;
}
let spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal); //метод easeout - анимация в обратном порядке
startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
drawRouletteWheel();
spinTimeout = setInterval('rotateWheel()'); // вызываем круг один раз, через определенный интервал времени
}
// При остановке прокрутки, будет показывать число по середине круга.

/*function stopRotateWheel() {
let degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
let arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
let index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
ctx.save();
ctx.font = 'bold 32px sans-serif';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 2;
ctx.shadowColor   = "black";
let text = quienes[index]
ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
ctx.restore();
alert(text);

}*/

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
let ts = (t /= d) * t;
let tc = ts * t;
return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
}

function spin() {
spinAngleStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 16); //random - Возвращает случайное число между 0 и 1 * 100
spinTime = 0;
spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1500;
rotateWheel();
}
drawRouletteWheel();
```

```html
<canvas id="wheelcanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<submit><a class="spin__button" type="button" onclick="spin();" id="btn_rodar" href="#">Крути</a></submit>
```

---

Можно отрисовать полноценный цветной круг с черной границей до рулетки, поверх него отрисовать белый (в цвет фона):

```
ctx.save();
    
ctx.fillStyle = colors[0];
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius + 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius + 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();   

ctx.restore();
```

```js
var colors = ["#0169D3"];
var quienes = ["ничего", "скидка на все 300руб.", "скидка на все 10%", "увы, в другой раз", "скидка на все 5%",
"секретная акция", "подарок сюрприз", "скидка на все 1000 руб.", "увы, в другой раз", "бесплатная", "доставка"
];

var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / 5;
var spinTimeout = null;
var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 10;
var spinTimeTotal = 10;
var ctx;

function drawRouletteWheel() {
let canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");
if (canvas.getContext) {
    let outsideRadius = 190;
    let textRadius = 110;
    let insideRadius = 30;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    
    ctx.save();
    
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[0];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius + 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius + 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();   

    ctx.restore();
    
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black"; // Цвет границ
    ctx.font = 'bold 14px sans-serif';

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let angle = startAngle + i * arc;
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
    ctx.beginPath(); //контур
    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false); //дуга
    ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true); //дуга
    ctx.stroke(); //фигура
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
    ctx.shadowColor = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
    ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 3 + Math.PI / 150); //Поворачиваем текст
    let text = quienes[i];
    ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0); //fillText - текст с заливкой. 
    ctx.restore(); //Возвращает ранее сохраненное состояние и атрибуты
    }

    //Arrow
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'navy'; // Set line colour.
    ctx.fillStyle = 'aqua'; // Set fill colour.
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath(); // Begin path.
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 6, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 15, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 33));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 15, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}
}

function rotateWheel() {
clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
spinTime = spinTime + 10; //делай оборот больше 360 градусов
if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    return;
}
let spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal); //метод easeout - анимация в обратном порядке
startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
drawRouletteWheel();
spinTimeout = setInterval('rotateWheel()'); // вызываем круг один раз, через определенный интервал времени
}
// При остановке прокрутки, будет показывать число по середине круга.

/*function stopRotateWheel() {
let degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
let arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
let index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
ctx.save();
ctx.font = 'bold 32px sans-serif';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 2;
ctx.shadowColor   = "black";
let text = quienes[index]
ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
ctx.restore();
alert(text);

}*/

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
let ts = (t /= d) * t;
let tc = ts * t;
return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
}

function spin() {
spinAngleStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 16); //random - Возвращает случайное число между 0 и 1 * 100
spinTime = 0;
spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1500;
rotateWheel();
}
drawRouletteWheel();
```

```html
<canvas id="wheelcanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<submit><a class="spin__button" type="button" onclick="spin();" id="btn_rodar" href="#">Крути</a></submit>
```

---

Дополнительные кружочки проще всего добавить в цикл, где отрисовывается текст, стиль применяется тот же.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250 - outsideRadius + 34, 0, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```js
var colors = ["#0169D3"];
var quienes = ["ничего", "скидка на все 300руб.", "скидка на все 10%", "увы, в другой раз", "скидка на все 5%",
"секретная акция", "подарок сюрприз", "скидка на все 1000 руб.", "увы, в другой раз", "бесплатная", "доставка"
];

var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / 5;
var spinTimeout = null;
var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 10;
var spinTimeTotal = 10;
var ctx;

function drawRouletteWheel() {
let canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");
if (canvas.getContext) {
    let outsideRadius = 190;
    let textRadius = 110;
    let insideRadius = 30;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black"; // Цвет границ
    
    ctx.save();
    
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[0];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius + 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius + 7, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();   
    
    ctx.restore();
    
    ctx.font = 'bold 14px sans-serif';

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    
    
    let angle = startAngle + i * arc;
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
    ctx.beginPath(); //контур
    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false); //дуга
    ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true); //дуга
    ctx.stroke(); //фигура
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
    ctx.shadowColor = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
    ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 3 + Math.PI / 150); //Поворачиваем текст
    let text = quienes[i];
    ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0); //fillText - текст с заливкой.
    
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250 - outsideRadius + 34, 0, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    //ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.restore(); //Возвращает ранее сохраненное состояние и атрибуты
    }

    //Arrow
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'navy'; // Set line colour.
    ctx.fillStyle = 'aqua'; // Set fill colour.
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath(); // Begin path.
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 6, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 15, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 33));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 15, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius - 15));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 6, 250 - (outsideRadius + 15));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}
}

function rotateWheel() {
clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
spinTime = spinTime + 10; //делай оборот больше 360 градусов
if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    return;
}
let spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal); //метод easeout - анимация в обратном порядке
startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
drawRouletteWheel();
spinTimeout = setInterval('rotateWheel()'); // вызываем круг один раз, через определенный интервал времени
}
// При остановке прокрутки, будет показывать число по середине круга.

/*function stopRotateWheel() {
let degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
let arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
let index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
ctx.save();
ctx.font = 'bold 32px sans-serif';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 2;
ctx.shadowColor   = "black";
let text = quienes[index]
ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
ctx.restore();
alert(text);

}*/

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
let ts = (t /= d) * t;
let tc = ts * t;
return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
}

function spin() {
spinAngleStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 16); //random - Возвращает случайное число между 0 и 1 * 100
spinTime = 0;
spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1500;
rotateWheel();
}
drawRouletteWheel();
```

```html
<canvas id="wheelcanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<submit><a class="spin__button" type="button" onclick="spin();" id="btn_rodar" href="#">Крути</a></submit>
```

Comment: Спасибо, что дал направления)

Comment: Скорее наоборот, тупо дал дурацкие решения сиюминутной проблемы. А в целом тут бы сильно поработать над оптимизацией, да и над дизайном)))

Comment: еще не дошел, доделываю верстку) И после идет дизайн с обводками))

Comment: Был еще вариант с готовой библиотекой на js, но там слишком легко. Мне стало интересно на canvas, вот теперь сижу мучаюсь))

Comment: Я лично никаких библиотек не принимаю, кроме Three.js, уж больно на родном WebGL для меня сложно пока))

Comment: просто там правда библиотека готовая, остается только выставить. А вот с canvas прям уже неделю потею. А вот про three.js я ничего не знаю, но посмотрю спасибо) Я в мире разрабов всего 3 месяца))) Так что я понял, что ты ощутил, когда увидел мой код))